# How to restrict my input type="file" to accept only png image files not working in Firefox

Tags: html, input

I am using input type="file", Now my requirement is that I only want to select png images, that is when I select browse a "png" filter should be applied.

I have referred `www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp` and below is the code I am using, this works fine with Chrome but does not work with Firefox and IE.

Please can anyone help me understand what wrong I must be doing ?

```
 <h2>Below uses accept="image/*"</h2>
 <input type="file" name="pic1" accept="image/*" /> 

 <h2>Below I need to accept only for png</h2>
 <input type="file" name="pic1" accept="image/png" />
```

​Here is a fiddle link to it http://jsfiddle.net/Jcgja/2/

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) will tell you why w3schools are not the best resource for all things web.

Comment: You'll need *server side* validation of file type. I don't think there is a way to do this in *all* browsers.

Comment: The problem with w3schools is that they show up among the top results in google so most people go there.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for guiding me to such an informative site, I spent almost an hour on it, now back to the problem :P

Comment: I believe you got some answers... The functionality is not supported in most browsers.

Comment: This is only useful to limit files displayed to the users in the browsing window, but it will not replace server side validation as it will not work on all browsers.

Comment: you can simply use `<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png" />`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to validate it through java script. Below is the code for java script validation

```
function CheckFileName() {
        var fileName = document.getElementById("uploadFile").value
        if (fileName == "") {
            alert("Browse to upload a valid File with png extension");
            return false;
        }
        else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "PNG")
            return true;
        else {
            alert("File with " + fileName.split(".")[1] + " is invalid. Upload a validfile with png extensions");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If a file has more than one dot this solution will fail. For example: **myfile.png.jpg** file will be valid and **myfile.jpg.png** will be an invalid file.

Answer (score 6):

The browser support information on that page of w3schools is not correct.

If you check this page, you see that the `accept` attribute it's not implemented in Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input

Update:
The `accept` attribute is now implemented in Firefox, but users who don't have a recent version still won't have the support.

Comment: This isn't actual anymore, it is supported since Firefox 16

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the 'accept' attribute is not properly supported by any of the major browsers. You could use a javascript validation on the form onsubmit event to verify if the file type is correct, returning false otherwise.

Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads should be validated on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["pic1"]["type"] == "image/png")
{
if ($_FILES["pic1"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["pic1"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["pic1"]["tmp_name"];
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

This is just the validation of the type of file. Not the whole upload script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function onChane event of a file function

```
filesChange() {
        checkFile();
        } 
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFile() {
    var fileElement = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
    var fileExtension = "";
    if (fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
        fileExtension = fileElement.value.substring(fileElement.value.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileElement.value.length);
    }
    if (fileExtension == "gif") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("You must select a GIF file for upload");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, accepted solution won't work with a file name with several "." in it. This should handle it better, it is more bug-proof and flexible, and **you can manage accepted extensions by editing the array**.

```
function checkFileExtension() {
    var fileName = document.getElementById("uploadFile").value;

    if(!fileName)
      return false;

    var extension = fileName.split(".");
    if(extension && extension.length > 1){
        extension = [extension.length-1].toUpperCase();
        if (["PNG"].indexOf(extension) != -1)
            return true;
        else{
            alert("Browse to upload a valid File with png extension");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Browse to upload a valid File with png extension");
        return false;
    }
}
```