# How can restrict to upload the photo according to the type of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have new task that is when user upload an image then it check by the coding which type of image is uploaded by the the user.If i want only jpg and png images to upload an image not give permission for gif and jpeg or etc . How can i set criteria or coding for that.

Please help me hope you understand my question.

Comment: Here's a hint... this is not a JavaScript question...

Comment: Also, with answer below by user*, use server side code to check for validity of files uploaded. For Example, in PHP, you can check within Array  $FILES. File type: $_FILES["file"]["type"]. More here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I want this code in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This will allow only image files(*.png,*.jpg...) to be uploaded

```
<input type="file"  name="attachment[]" multiple="1" accept="image/*" id="js_5">
```

This link should help you....-> [Restriction on Upload: W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

-> [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381999/how-to-restrict-my-input-type-file-to-accept-only-png-image-files-not-working)

Comment: thank you but i want... Example: I am uploading image .png but it is restricted on upload .So at the time uploading .png image it show error msg that you are not able to upload.

Comment: Can I repeat my Question?

Comment: Look at the stackoverflow link above....It has javascript validation if you don't want php validation