# Input accept attribute in Firefox

Tags: html, forms, firefox

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility) `accept=[MIME type]` is supported in Firefox. However, I tried the following to no avail:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/html">
```

It doesn't filter the `HTML` files: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9dT2Y/)**.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: How are you testing it? What result did you expect? What result did you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict my input type="file" to accept only png image files not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381999/how-to-restrict-my-input-type-file-to-accept-only-png-image-files-not-working)

Comment: Contrary to what MDN says, Firefox supports only the values `image/*`, `audio/*`, and `video/*` for `accept`. There have apparently been attempts at fixing this, but it is unclear what the exact status is. The answers to the duplicate question suggest JavaScript check as a workaround.

Comment: It kind of works for me. But not really. By default it selects "All files" in the file picker dropdown, but I can manually select "html file".

Comment: @evilpie: ...and when you select "html file" it shows no HTML files!

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: JavaScript validation and the `accept` attribute do different things: the `accept` attribute filters the files you see in the `Open` dialog so you can easily find and work with the desired files among the clutter while you can still select `All Files` and see/select other files. But the JavaScript validation doesn't filter the files you see and just doesn't allow you to upload the unwanted ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Firefox bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826185

Fortunately, it appears there is a patch for the issue that should be reviewed soon.

Comment: Whether it’s a bug or not depends on the interpretation. As it is, it seems to be an intentional feature in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug or not yet fully implemented.