# perform client side validation on file input - accept attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation, client-side

I'm currently trying to build a small website in Visual Studio, ASP.net with C#. 
The user has to upload a file, but I only want to accept Excel files.

Currently I already have this piece of server side validation:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file){
  if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0){
      string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      if (fileName.EndsWith(".xlsx")) //enkel gewoon Excel bestand wordt aanvaard. {
           ...
```

That does the trick, but I don't know how to solely allow Excel files in the client side. I currently have this, but it doesn't limit the user yet. I can still upload whatever file I want.

```
<input type="file" name="file" value="Bestand kiezen" accept=".xlsx" />
```

I'm aware that client side limitation isn't 100% fool proof, but I'd like to implement the feature  anyway. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I got the answer thanks to the fellas below. I ended up using this, which shows .xls and .xlsx files

```
<input type="file" name="file" value="Bestand kiezen" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

Comment: This might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11834872/1870760
Check the accept attribute on the excel cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `accept` attribute is supported by some browsers but not all, and the level of support varies; see e.g. answers to [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) and [Input accept attribute in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590301/input-accept-attribute-in-firefox)

Note that `accept=".xlsx"` restricts, on supporting browser, the input to files that have a filename extensions of `.xlsx`, thereby usually ignoring Excel files created with older versions of Excel, which produce `.xls` files. Generally, any software that can handle `.xlsx` can handle `.xls` as well.

Comment: Mmhmm, that sort of worked, yes. The pop up window still uses standard *.* files, but it also has the option to use my specified types. thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />`
it should work